# JavaFx self contained application updater

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javafx

How I can I create an updater for a self contained application in JavaFX (I used a eclipse ant script with Inno Setup)? I created a small jar to update my application the problem is that when the application is installed on the user's machine and the main application calls this updater jar, the jvm used is not the same, it is the system, then so requiring the Users have a virtual machine. I noticed that the runtime folder does not have the wrappers (java.exe). Can i reutilize the application jvm? How I solve this problem?

Note: To execute a jar file I am using `getRuntime().exec()` command.

Comment: Why not use [tag:java-web-start]?

Comment: This is a exclusive desktop application. Seems unusual but this is it. I don't want that the user have to open the browser just to update the program

Comment: No browsing is required; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).